# How to use current updated value in useCallback hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, material-ui, stepper

```
const initialPersonalDetails = {
  firstName: '',
  mobile: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: '',
  city: '',
  dob: null,
};

const initalBankDetails = {
  bankName: '',
  accno: '',
  ifsccode: '',
  aadhar: '',
  pan: '',
};
```

this is the initial values which is in parent component

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({
  personalDetails: initialPersonalDetails,
  bankDetails: initalBankDetails,
});
```

initial this value in state

this is the next and back button state (move forword for next form

```
const [allowNext, setAllowNext] = useState(false)
```

this is the state of multi stepper forms

```
const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
```

onSuccess is the funtion if the form is successfully filled then it move forword

```
const OnSuccess = useCallback(
  (values) => {
    console.log('user', allowNext);
    const currentData = { ...user };
    setUser((user) => {
      if (activeStep == 0) {
        currentData.personalDetails = values;
        return currentData;
      }
      if (activeStep == 1) {
        currentData.bankDetails = values;
        return currentData;
      }
      return user;
    });

    setAllowNext((allowNext) => {
      if (allowNext === false) {
        return true;
      }
      return allowNext;
    });
  },
  [allowNext]
);
```

form is prifilled but it can't be edit

form is prifilled but it cannot edit. If I remove the callback then also the same problem going on. when I fill up the personal details and on clicking on next button it move to bankdetails but when i click on back button the form is prifilled but not get edit.

Comment: `const currentData = {...user}` needs to go *inside* of the updater callback that you're passing to `setUser`

Comment: …and the dependencies array of the `useCallback` should be `[activeStep]`, not `[allowNext]`